# R: Conditionally remove duplicated rows

Tags: r

I have a large ordered data frame in R that contains two columns, "gene" and "rank", and I would like to remove the second occurrence of the duplicated row in the positive direction **AND** the first occurrence of the duplicated row in the negative direction.

For example, in the following data set, I would like to remove lines 6262 and 12200, such that I keep the genes with the greatest rank value in either direction:

```
> head(a_ordered, n=10)
              gene     rank
10597      SLC37A1  2.827330
6262       SLC37A1  2.700882
12504         UBR4  2.698938
10934        SP110  2.690130
1563         CALB1  2.633179
6031  LOC100128239 -2.499959
6718        MBTPS1 -2.513134
1528          CA14 -2.549553
12200        NXPE3 -2.850011
7978         NXPE3 -3.153175
```

Becomes,

```
 > head(a_ordered, n=10)
                  gene     rank
    10597      SLC37A1  2.827330
    12504         UBR4  2.698938
    10934        SP110  2.690130
    1563         CALB1  2.633179
    6031  LOC100128239 -2.499959
    6718        MBTPS1 -2.513134
    1528          CA14 -2.549553
    7978         NXPE3 -3.153175
```

Thank you!

Comment: @RichScriven, the rank value corresponds to an associated fold change in gene expression for the particular gene of interest, and I would like to keep the gene that shows the strongest down-regulation value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::filter` to keep those rows for which `abs(rank) == max(abs(rank))` grouped by `gene`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% group_by(gene) %>% filter(abs(rank) == max(abs(rank)))
##Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
##Groups: gene [8]
##
##     ID         gene      rank
##  <int>        <chr>     <dbl>
##1 10597      SLC37A1  2.827330
##2 12504         UBR4  2.698938
##3 10934        SP110  2.690130
##4  1563        CALB1  2.633179
##5  6031 LOC100128239 -2.499959
##6  6718       MBTPS1 -2.513134
##7  1528         CA14 -2.549553
##8  7978        NXPE3 -3.153175
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(10597L, 6262L, 12504L, 10934L, 1563L, 6031L, 
6718L, 1528L, 12200L, 7978L), gene = c("SLC37A1", "SLC37A1", 
"UBR4", "SP110", "CALB1", "LOC100128239", "MBTPS1", "CA14", "NXPE3", 
"NXPE3"), rank = c(2.82733, 2.700882, 2.698938, 2.69013, 2.633179, 
-2.499959, -2.513134, -2.549553, -2.850011, -3.153175)), .Names = c("ID", 
"gene", "rank"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
##      ID         gene      rank
##1  10597      SLC37A1  2.827330
##2   6262      SLC37A1  2.700882
##3  12504         UBR4  2.698938
##4  10934        SP110  2.690130
##5   1563        CALB1  2.633179
##6   6031 LOC100128239 -2.499959
##7   6718       MBTPS1 -2.513134
##8   1528         CA14 -2.549553
##9  12200        NXPE3 -2.850011
##10  7978        NXPE3 -3.153175
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the values that are most different from zero, you can use the squared value and then order the data frame accordingly

```
a_ordered$rank2 <- a_ordered$rank^2
a_ordered <- a_ordered[order(a_ordered$rank2, decreasing = TRUE),]
a_ordered <- a_ordered[-(duplicated(a_ordered$gene)==TRUE),]
```

Duplicated will go trough the column from top to bottom and flag the second (and third and so on) value as duplicate.